Is company under receivership in Washington State obligated to pay for use of occupied property before deciding to assume or reject lease?
Under Washington State law, it appears that companies under receivership have no hard and fast timeframe under which they are required to decide if they wish to assume or reject a lease executed before company entered receivership.  During this time when no formal decision to assume or reject lease has been made, is the receivership required to pay for the use and occupancy of the property?

Generally speaking, in a receivership, the receiver steps into the shoes of the person who would otherwise have management authority of the receivership estate.
The obligations and rights of a receiver are the same as the owner. Unlike a bankruptcy trustee, there is no holding in abeyance of the obligations of a debtor, including obligations related to a lease. The receiver is bound by the lease just as the owner would have been if there was no receivership.
The main difference is that the receiver's liability will usually be limited to the property of the receivership estate. The receiver will not ordinarily have personal liability for the liabilities of the receivership estate assets.

australia
A Receiver is appointed by a secured creditor(s) to gather up and sell the specific assets over which they have security (which may be all of a company's assets). It does not stop other creditors from enforcing their debts, possibly leading to administration or liquidation.
If the company has a lease over real property, the appointment of a receiver has no effect on its rights and obligations under that contract. Or any other type of contract.
That means if the company stops paying the rent, it is in breach, and the landlord can take whatever action the contract provides for that eventuality. It is also possible, even likely, that an "act of insolvency" (like having a receiver appointed) may be dealt with by the lease, usually allowing the landlord to terminate it without penalty.
